# Изменение внешнего вида <input type="radio>" при помощи CSS

Tags: css, css3

О том, как изменить внешний вид стандартного вида input я знаю. Например, с таким кодом проблем не возникнет:

```
<input id="r1" name="radio1" type="radio" />
<label for="r1">Option 1</label>
```

А вот как быть с зависимостью от input вложенного в label?

```
<span class="val">
<label><input type="radio">Option 1</label>
<label><input type="radio">Option 2</label>
<label><input type="radio">Option 3</label>
<label><input type="radio">Option 4</label>
</span>
```

То есть, задаем мы вид для label, input скрываем. А с выделением выбранного объекта получается тупик. Понятно, что вопрос можно решить простеньким скриптом. Но можно ли обойтись только стилями оформления?

Пример того, что хотелось бы получить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выделить тегом текст внутри label нет возможности, поэтому стандартный вариант input:checked + label для определения стилей активного значения не подходит.

Comment: а в чем принципиальная разница между первым и вторым вариантом? не уверен, но может быть вам стоит присвоить какой-либо класс к input и прописать стили для этого класса.

Comment: В чем именно у Вас проблема? покажите код css для input. Обычно label не влияет на визуализацию и выделение input.

Comment: Дополнил описание скриншотом. Хочу превратить выбор значений в более удобный вид. Но, при оформлении label не удается привязаться к выбранному input-у.

Answer (score 3):

текст внутри `label` обернуть в `span`

Пример

```css
.b-radio label{
  display: inline-block;  
}
.b-radio label input{
  display: none;
}
.b-radio label input + span{
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 30px 15px 30px;    
  white-space: nowrap;  
}
.b-radio label input + span:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 0;
  margin-top: -10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.b-radio label input:checked + span:before{
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-radio">
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" checked> 
  <span>Option 1</span>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span>Option 2</span>
</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. О такой подаче я писал. Если бы текст был обернут в какой-то тег, то проблем не возникло. Штука в том, что код генерируется системой и изменить его нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

## Костыль на flexbox'е

```css
label {
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input {
  margin: 0;
  flex: 0 0 2em;
  order: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
  visibility: hidden;
}

input:checked {
  order: 3;
}

label:after {
  content: "";
  flex: 0 0 2em;
  margin: -2em -.5em 0;
  background: silver;
  order: 2;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="r">Option 1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="r">Option 2</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="r">Option 3</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="r">Option 4</label>
```

## И инвертирование цвета

```css
label {
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input {
  margin: 0;
  flex: 0 0 2em;
  order: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
  visibility: hidden;
}

input:checked {
  order: 3;
}

label:after {
  content: "";
  flex: 0 0 2em;
  margin: -2em -.5em 0;
  background: white;
  order: 2;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="r">Option 1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="r">Option 2</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="r">Option 3</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="r">Option 4</label>
```

Кажется, надо ещё допилить взаимодействие с границами.
Ну и поддержку браузерами проверить у всего...

Comment: Использовал flex для выравнивания элементов по центру. А тут еще и подобное решение возможно. Буду разбираться и тестировать. Спасибо большое за наводку.